# Why is CORS better than just checking request.headers['origin'] = 'example.com?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I'm using Django REST framework. Why is it better to use CORS framework instead of just checking that the request origin is from my own site?

Why can't I just check in my view that `request.headers['origin']` (exists) and `request.headers['origin'] == 'example.com'` as opposed to using the Django CORS framework?

Comment: Because a middleware is applied to all requests, implementing the check in your views would mean adding the check to every single view instead of one place

Comment: @IainShelvington so from a safety perspective, if I only had one view, would it do the same thing as CORS or is CORS more secure?

Comment: You can implement CORS yourself and if your did it right it would _do the same thing_. A package that has been developed for almost ten years by dozens of contributors is almost always going to be more secure than something developed by a sole developer, for the same reason it is severely frowned upon to implement your own cryptography/authentication

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request.headers['origin']` For each resource/page then your resources/pages can  to be accessed on other domains . The problem is you have to configure it for each view . while you can use **CORS framwork** like  `django-cors-headers` witch is more secure  and you can  implement it with just few steps  and  Don't repeat yourself (DRY principle)  more than that There are a couple other [configurations](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/) that you can use to adapt it to your needs .